# Perl dots file name matching

Tags: regex, perl, filenames

I was trying to find something very specific of file name pattern matching in perl.

I have a series of files called:

```
AAA.test.xml and AAA.xml.
```

and I pass into the function the full file path.

I would like to compare the file name and if the file name is AAA.xml I would like to copy it to another directory.

This is my question: Is there a way I can compare the file name and check if it contains 2 dots within the name?

Edit:
Using REGEX is fine as well, I just don't know how to do it in perl

Answer (score 2):

If you have the filenames (it sounds like you do), you can just use a simple regex that checks for two literal periods. For instance:

```
if ($name =~ /\..*\./) { do stuff }
```

It's important to note that the character "." is special in regexes. The character sequence "." means a literal "."; the character sequence ".", with no backslash, means *any* character. Also, "*" means that the previous thing needs to be matched zero or more times.

So, the regex given above means "find a literal '.' character, then any number of anything, then another literal '.'".

Comment: Thank you! I imagined that, I remember that from pattern matching, but this is the first time doing it in perl, I was going to use glob, but you need an array of file names! thank you!